# Создать транзакцию с одного кошелька (отправляется 1 коин) на другой

Tags: python, transaction, bitcoin, криптография

Как с помощью pycoin (или иных аналогов) провести транзакцию с одного кошелька на другой (зная адрес кошелька отправителя и получателя)

Если есть возможность, приложите пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь проводить транзакции при помощи pycoin, то тебе стоит прочитать документацию по методу транзакций: https://pycoin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pycoin/coins/Tx.html#Tx

(Прости, что не расписал подробно, я не знаю всех подробностей транзакций криптовалюты)